# Cannot capture an PHP exception from an inactive MySql server when using Zend transactions

Tags: php, zend-framework, transactions, try-catch

I am trying to use transactions in the Zend Framework and have a working script.

However, under testing I noticed that a try/catch function will catch any exception except one caused by the Mysql server being inactive.

Is this supposed to happen?  If my server crashes I am worried that an ugly Zend exception would be returned and the application would cease to fail gracefully.

My code looks like this:

```
function insertInbox ($userId, $mail_id )
{   

    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();  

    $table = new Application_Model_DbTable_Inbox; 

    try {
        $db->beginTransaction();

        $data = array (
                   'user_id'    => $userId,
                   'mail_id'    => $mail_id
                   );

        $insertedId[] = $table -> insert($data);

        $db -> commit();

        return $insertedId;
        }

    catch(exception $e){ 
        $db->rollback();
        return "insert failed";//.$e;
        }   
}

$tt = insertInbox ( 666,666);   
print_r($tt);
```

A duplicate entry of similar exception is caught and the temporary custom error message -*insert failed*- is returned. But if I turn off the database server the php catch does not capture this error:

```
**Message:** SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Also, check your transactions are working.  I had the same issue, had to set it to `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();` for the transactions. But it depends on what you're extending from in your models.

Comment: The question is a little different that case1352 - which asks what the error is.  I know what the exception is. My question is why my try/catch sequence in the code catches most exceptions, but if I shut down my mysql sever to imitate a crash I fail to catch the resulting error.  Tried Zend_Db_Table_Abstract but still seems to occur.

Comment: Bigman - I should add the transactions rollback successfully under most tests.  It is just this server connection that escapes being caught.  Further, I tried a test cast without transactions and found I can catch an inactive server error if I am not using transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some database extensions of PHP try to create a database connection when none is established and a function is called, that requires one. In this case `$db->rollback()` itself throws an exception.

Comment: Great answer I have wrapped the rollback in a try/catch sequence and catch this error.  However, now get this error ... Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.  -- Do you know how to avoid this. It is now just an error rather than an exception.

Comment: This seems to be due to your [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/de/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) setting, which is meant to ease development and should be turned off in a production environment.